WebHTtrack doesn't download mp3 files
I'm using WebHTTrack 3.49.4. My Linux Distribution is Devuan Daedalus
I wanted to have offline access to a website www.germanveryeasy.com for learning German.
The entire mirroring operation has finished but the links to mp3 files (which contain the recordings of German pronunciation) don't play the audio.
I discovered that the mp3 files haven't been downloaded in the first place.
Scan rules
--disable-security-limits +*.mp3 +*.png -*.gif +*.jpg +*.jpeg +*.css +*.js -ad.doubleclick.net/*

Flow control:
N# connections = 100
Limits
Max. transfer rate = 0
Where am I going wrong? Can someone pitch in?

Does https://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/7526/7516/index.html help: Set Options / Scan rules: -* +www.example.com/*.htm +www.example.com/*.asp +*.mp3 ?

You'll need to install tidy, it's on the repository.
The tedious part will be getting the base URL for the .mp3 files.
On the main page, you will need to go down the entire left menu, click each section.

Find a sound file and play it.
Press Ctrl + I to open "Page info"


Make a directory, I used temp_files, and create a file inside that directory called base_urls.txt with the following:
adjective-declension
apostrophe
colors
comparative-and-superlative
conjunctions
countries-in-german
family-in-german
feminine-noun-gender
future-in-german
geography-in-german
german-adverbs
german-declension
greetings
haben
imperative
informal-you-in-german
interrogation-in-german
irregular-verbs-in-german
konjunktiv-i
konjunktiv-ii
learning-german-from-zero
masculine-noun-gender
mathematics-in-german
modal-verbs
negation-affirmation
neuter-noun-gender
noun-declension
numbers-in-german
passive
past-perfect
perfekt
plural
practical
prepositions-in-german
present
preterite
pronouns
reflexive-verbs
relative-clauses
sein
sentence-structure
separable-verbs
time-in-german
verb
verb-conjugation
vocabulary
werden

As the image shows above, this is the source path for the 'Greetings' page's sound files:
https://audio.alemansencillo.com/audio/saludo-y-presentacion-en-aleman/Hallo.mp3

Example base_urls.txt:
greetings https://audio.alemansencillo.com/audio/saludo-y-presentacion-en-aleman/
german-declension https://audio.alemansencillo.com/audio/la-declinacion-alemana/

Open base_urls.txt and add the base URL's, removing the .mp3 file name, leaving the /.  Only 46 more to go. ;-)
Just to clarify:
Open a browser tab to https://www.germanveryeasy.com/.  You can use base_urls.txt for navigation. Just copy/paste each line after the ending / in the browser tab and press enter.  Find a sound icon, play it, press Ctrl + I, click the Media tab, find the sound you just played in the address list.  Right click > Copy.  Paste into base_urls.txt to the corresponding URL's name, leaving a space between them.  Remove the title_of_file.mp3, leaving the /.  On to the next URL.

Now that you have all the base URL's, create another file inside that directory. Use the following script, and call it get_audio.sh:
#!/bin/bash

# Create a working directory
mkdir -p html && cd html

# Extract URLs from the grammar page index
wget 'https://www.germanveryeasy.com/grammar'
tidy grammar 2>/dev/null > grammer.html && rm grammar

cat grammer.html | grep -oP "(?<=href=\')[^']*" | grep -v www > index.tmp

sed -e '1d;3d;5d;6d' index.tmp > ../wget_list.txt

cd .. && rm -rf ./html

# Create extract directory and navigate into it
mkdir -p extract && cd extract
mv ../wget_list.txt ./

# Download the HTML pages listed in wget_list.txt
wget -B 'https://www.germanveryeasy.com' --input-file=wget_list.txt && rm wget_list.txt

# Remove extract artifact if it exists
rm -f practical.1

# Process each HTML file to extract track names
for html_file in *; do
    if [[ -f "$html_file" ]]; then
        cat "$html_file" | grep -A 1 'onclick=' | grep -oP "(?<=Listen\(\').*?(?=\'\)\;\")" > "${html_file}.txt"
        mkdir -p "../audio"
    fi
done

# Create a temporary file to hold all the URLs for wget
temp_file=$(mktemp)

# Read the base_urls.txt and process each directory
while read -r line; do
    dir_name=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
    base_url=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')
    
    text_file="./${dir_name}.txt"

    if [[ -f "$text_file" ]]; then
        # Append .mp3 to each line and construct full URLs
        while read -r track; do
            echo "${base_url}${track}.mp3"
        done < "$text_file" >> "$temp_file"
        
        rm "$text_file"
    else
        echo "Text file $text_file not found, skipping..."
    fi
done < ../base_urls.txt

# Download all audio files into the audio directory
wget -P ../audio --input-file="$temp_file"

# Clean up temporary file
rm "$temp_file"

exit 0

Now, run chmod +x get_audio.sh and then run it: ./get_audio.sh
I tested two of the base URL's:
greetings https://audio.alemansencillo.com/audio/saludo-y-presentacion-en-aleman/
german-declension https://audio.alemansencillo.com/audio/la-declinacion-alemana/


Now here is the trick to making the files play.  Move the audio directory into the site directory.  There is a script at the top of each html file that controls the onclick playback.  You need to change every one of them to the local path instead of //audio.alemansencillo.com...  All of them in the root directory, and all of them in m.
Create a file called replace_js.sh in the website folder and use the following:
#!/bin/bash

# Define the search patterns and replacement strings
search_pattern1="'//audio.alemansencillo.com/audio/[^']*"
search_pattern2="'//audio2.alemansencillo.com/audio/[^']*"
replace_string_current="'./audio/"
replace_string_m="'../audio/"

# Function to replace patterns in files in the current directory
replace_pattern_in_file_current() {
    local file=$1
    local search_pattern=$2
    local replace_string=$3
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
        sed -i "s|$search_pattern|$replace_string|g" "$file"
        echo "Processed $file with pattern $search_pattern in current directory"
    else
        echo "File $file not found, skipping..."
    fi
}

# Function to replace patterns in files in the ./m directory
replace_pattern_in_file_m() {
    local file=$1
    local search_pattern=$2
    local replace_string=$3
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
        sed -i "s|$search_pattern|$replace_string|g" "$file"
        echo "Processed $file with pattern $search_pattern in ./m directory"
    else
        echo "File $file not found, skipping..."
    fi
}

# Process HTML files in the current directory with the first pattern
for html_file in *.html; do
    replace_pattern_in_file_current "$html_file" "$search_pattern1" "$replace_string_current"
done

# Process HTML files in the current directory with the second pattern
for html_file in *.html; do
    replace_pattern_in_file_current "$html_file" "$search_pattern2" "$replace_string_current"
done

# Process HTML files in the ./m directory with the first pattern
if [[ -d "./m" ]]; then
    for html_file in ./m/*.html; do
        replace_pattern_in_file_m "$html_file" "$search_pattern1" "$replace_string_m"
    done
else
    echo "Directory ./m not found, skipping..."
fi

# Process HTML files in the ./m directory with the second pattern
if [[ -d "./m" ]]; then
    for html_file in ./m/*.html; do
        replace_pattern_in_file_m "$html_file" "$search_pattern2" "$replace_string_m"
    done
else
    echo "Directory ./m not found, skipping..."
fi

echo "Replacement complete."

Run chmod +x replace_js.sh and then run it: ./replace_js.sh
The audio folder with the mp3 files is set to the proper path in the script that calls them onclick.
Now, everything should be functional!

I've done a little debugging.  It seems to still play by clicking the word, but without the server side includes, the little sound icon and a few other minor things don't quite display correctly. It's purely cosmetic.
If I run it with five-server, it solves the glitches for things that require the client/server back end.

Thank you very much for your answer. Sorry for the delayed reply. What should I do if I need the mp3 files to play upon clicking the link on the website itself. (The website has been downloaded in entirely. Only the audio files were left out. So the links are intact)

@vrgovinda  Okay.  Massive do over.  I made some incorrect assumptions about the directory structure.  This is the proper way to do it.  Let me know if you hit any snags, we'll make it happen!
